# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header not added

Tags: .htaccess, cors

I want to add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` to a response on an Apache 2.2 server. My `.htaccess` file looks like this.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN (.*) ORIGIN=$1
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN}e" env=ORIGIN
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Link, Location, Accept-Post, Content-Type, Slug, Origin"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/turtle
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://example/me.ttl [R=303]
```

On line 5 I set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`. But the resulting response has `''` for this header. When I add line 5 also at the end of the file, resulting in the following

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN (.*) ORIGIN=$1
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN}e" env=ORIGIN
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Link, Location, Accept-Post, Content-Type, Slug, Origin"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/turtle
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://example/me.ttl [R=303]
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

the value of `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is `'true, true'`. While I want it to be only `'true'`.
Does anybody know what the reason is for this behaviour?

EDIT: I've tried to put `''` in line 5 in order to get `'true'` at the end, but then I get just `''`.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you change the last line to `Header merge Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"` (that is if instead of `set`, you use `merge`)

Comment: That results in the same response of `'true, true'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my hosting and although they said that nothing is wrong on their side, suddenly it works...